# change the title of comments in my wp template

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, wordpress-theming

Ok i have website, and want to change Leave Reply string near the bottom of the page. It is wordpress template, and i looked all over the page to find where is that string located. I ended up on `get_the_title()` function inside `wp-incledes`. I watched inside comment box in wp-admin, and there is no string like that.

Here is the link, if you can give me idea.

```
http://zivibolje.com/pobedite-nesanicu-u-par-koraka/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** * update * **

Your theme uses the function `comment_form()` ([reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)). You can add arguments to that function, for instance:

`comment_form(array('title_reply' => 'Leave a reply' ));`

Go to your theme editor, select `comments.php` and at the second to last rule replace `comment_form();` with the code above. Replace 'Leave a reply' with your own text of course.

Comment: I figured that, in my other themes that was the case, but not here.  here is my comment.php


<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
                       <h3 id="comments-title"><?php
                       printf( _n( 'Trenutno jedan komentar %2$s',
'%1$s komentara %2$s',
get_comments_number(), '' ),
                       number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<em>' .
get_the_title('ostavi komentar') . '</em>' );
                       ?></h3>

Comment: That's the part that says '2 comments' above the actual comments. On your site it says '2 komentara', which I take it is the right text? Lower in the template (second to last rule) is the part that says 'leave a reply'.

Comment: I did what you said, and still same thing. From where it even come that string Leave a reply, when it is no where to be found in code.

Comment: See the code reference I linked. `comment_form()` uses an array of arguments to set the comment form, and one of the default values is the 'Leave a reply' for the title. What happens if you remove `comment_form()` from the template entirely?

Comment: also, what happens if you do `comment_form(array('title_reply' => __('Your text here') ));` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check on your **comments.php** file on your theme folder. Search for **reply-title**

Comment: I checked there already. string Leave reply is not here. I cannot change  <h3 id="reply-title">

Comment: Then look in your functions.php it may be there. (Again in your theme folder)

Comment: looked there too. I even downloaded entire theme, and searched for string Leave reply, no where to be found.